# How can I export a previous installation under Wine to the PlayOnLinux folder?

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I have some programs and games installed with Wine and I wonder if it's possible manage this applications with PlayOnLinux. There was a plugin called "Wine Import" to do this, but seems to be obsolete.

What can I do? Should I copy my Wine folder and paste it in the Playonlinux directory?

Answer (score 1):

The **Wine import plugin** works fine.

**OR**

copy the whole .wine folder with registry entries.
to:

```
/home/user/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/
```

**PlayOnLinux For the Precise version**

Type the following commands:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -

sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Comment: Do you know where I can download the plugin? It's not present in the PlayOnLinux options.

Comment: In my Ubuntu 12.04 installation of PlayOnLinux (see edited answer) the plugin is present and works.

Comment: I installed playonlinux via PPA, but the wine import plugin is still missing.